# Does acetophenone show haloform reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, halides, halogenation, immiscibility

Although acetophenone is a methyl ketone, as it is aromatic, it is immiscible in H2O so the last step in the haloform reaction should not occur?

I couldn't find any source regarding the haloform reaction of acetophenone.

Comment: Who said it will not give: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=does+acetophenone+give+iodoform+test&prmd=inv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiO8e3GiYviAhWHtI8KHdbIDZ8Q_AUoAXoECA0QAQ&biw=360&bih=560&dpr=2

Comment: No creditable research paper shows. My teacher told that it doesn't show.

Comment: Your teacher may be wrong.check http://www.webassign.net/sample/ncsumeorgchem2/lab_4/manual.html  which is a lab experiment desinged for the same  acetophenone.

Comment: A phase transfer catalyst can be used in last step

Answer (score 3):

Fuson and Bull [*Chem. Rev.*, **15**, 275 (1934)] found acetophenone to give a positive iodoform **test**. They modified the usual procedure, adding dioxane as a cosolvent to better dissolve water-insoluble compounds, since the purely-aqueous method is "uncertain and likely to be misleading" for water-insoluble compounds.

Also cited by those authors as proof of positive haloform test for acetophenone are the following: [Lieben, *Ann. Spl. Bd.*, **7**, 218 (1870)](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uiug.30112018225695&view=1up&seq=230); [Kramer, *Ber.*, **13*, 1000 (1880)](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.c047061980&view=1up&seq=1010); and Cuculescu, *Bul. Fac. Stiinte Cernauti*, **2**, 137 (1928).